# Parallel workflow doesn't process jobs in parallel

Tags: .net, powershell, workflow, powershell-4.0

I'm very new to workflows and PS in general. [Here's my attempt at scripting a parallel process using a workflow.](https://github.com/dkennedy778/BTCParser/blob/master/twitterScraperScript.ps1)

```
Set-Location -Path "D:/Users/Derek/PostGrad/BTCParser"
$startDate = Get-Date "1/12/2018"
$currentDate = Get-Date
$temp = $currentDate.ToShortDateString

$ts = New-TimeSpan -Start $startDate -End $currentDate
$DayCount = $ts.Days
$parseDate = $startDate
$dateList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)
For ($i = 0; $i -lt $DayCount; $i++){ #I miss you already python
  $dateList.Add($parseDate)
  $parseDate = $parseDate.AddDays(1)
}
$DayCount
scraper($dateList)


Workflow scraper{

  param(
  [Parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
  [System.Collections.ArrayList]$dateList
  )

    ForEach -Parallel ($date in $dateList)
    {      
          $endDate = $date.AddDays(1)
          $startDateString = $date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
          $endDateString = $endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
          $twitterScraperString = $startDateString + "BTCtweets.json"

          twitterscraper "Bitcoin OR BTC " -begindate $startDateString -enddate $endDateString --"limit" 20 -o =$twitterScraperString  
    }
```

}

Right now the process just executes sequentially, a parser is run and once it finishes its execution another process gets started.

[Check out the official windows documentation on workflows, this is the part I designed my script around.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/sma/overview-powershell-workflows?view=sc-sma-1711)

> You can use the ForEach -Parallel construct to process commands for each item in a collection concurrently. The items in the collection are processed in parallel while the commands in the script block run sequentially. This uses the syntax shown below. In this case, Activity1 will start at the same time for all items in the collection. For each item, Activity2 will start after Activity1 is complete. Activity3 will start only after both Activity1 and Activity2 have completed for all items.
>   PowerShell

```
ForEach -Parallel ($<item> in $<collection>)
 {
   <Activity1>
   <Activity2>
}
<Activity3>
```

Via my interpretation, everything in my for each loop constitutes activity 1, and should be executed in parallel. Am I missing an identifying tag here or something? As I said before, the process just executes for every date sequentially.

Also if there are any superusers out there, I'd like to further fine tune this process so that only a certain number of activities are launched in parallel at a time. For example, if I have 20 dates I only want 10 date activities to be running at once. This is because the scraper holds all of its scraped data in memory until it's completed, and I don't want to risk having all of my scraping processes fail because they ran out of memory.

[Here's a sequential loop I made that'll fulfill that function, but I have no clue how to parallelize it.](https://pastebin.com/7H7kEvbU) Any slick ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to include your pertinent code in the question. Links and repositories can go down and change. The code we need to look at should be here. I would also try to limit yourself to one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure workflows are what you should be looking for. Review some of the [basics of workflows](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/12/26/powershell-workflows-the-basics/). My sense is that they're more meant for farming jobs out to many workstations and/or servers. There are language restrictions in workflows, too, that will add more frustration.

Your loop looks like it does a little bit of date arithmetic and string processing, then calls `twitterscraper "Bitcoin OR BTC " ...` to get data from another process. I suspect you only really need the `twitscraper` call to run asynchronously. [Powershell Jobs](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/12/31/using-windows-powershell-jobs/) are probably a better fit for this case.

Comment: Thanks veefu, I'll look into them